# Trying to loop through items in an object that are named strIngredients 1-15

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

```
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#mainContent').empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: randomDrinksURL,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var mainContent = $('#mainContent');
        mainContent.append(`
        <img src='${response.drinks[0].strDrinkThumb}'>
        <p>${response.drinks[0].strDrink}</p>
        <p>${response.drinks[0].strMeasure1} of ${response.drinks[0].strIngredient1}</p>
        <p> ${response.drinks[0].strInstructions}</p>
        `);
    });
```

The object lists all the ingredients and measurements from 1 - 15 and I am trying to find a way to go through them without having to write each one individually but it also needs to be able to know when to stop if the value is = null

I tried some sort of for loop and could not get that to work to save my life. any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would something like this do the thing ?

```js
let html = `
        <img src='${response.drinks[0].strDrinkThumb}'>
        <p>${response.drinks[0].strDrink}</p>
        `

for (var i = 1; i<= 15; i++) {
  let ingredient= "strIngredient" + i;
  let measure= "strMeasure" + i;
  if (response.drinks[0][measure] && response.drinks[0][ingredient]) {
    html += `<p>${response.drinks[0][measure]} of ${response.drinks[0][ingredient]}</p>`
  }
}

html += `<p> ${response.drinks[0].strInstructions}</p>`

mainContent.append(html)
```

***edited***
added null condition

Comment: that does work to list all of them, but it also lists the other nonexistent ones and displays null of null